# Android realtime sql database search functionality

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sqlite, android-search

I am developing an android appstore (appmarket) application.

Files information is in sql database. I use Json for retrieving the information of the files from web sql database.

How can I add realtime search functionality for my appsore? I mean typing some words bring some results as a list below the edit text field as user types.

Answer (score 0):

Try AutoCompleteTextView.

[Refer This](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html)